# What is the minimum number of persons required for a jumuah jama'ath?

Tags: fiqh, jumuah, jamaat

I heard someone saying 50, someone as 25 and someone says 3.

My friend's brother is studying engineering in a college with total of 5 to 10 muslim boys. They are not allowed to go out for `Jumuah`. Can they pray jummah jama'at in hostel room?

What is the minimum number of persons required for conducting a jummah jama'ath prayer?

I need authentic references for this.

Answer (score 8):

it's a bit hard to translate from the textbook but i will try my best. Like you said there is a disagreement between scientists about the minimum number , actually there is 15 different opinions all mentioned by El Hafyz in his book "El Fath" , the preponderant opinion is that the friday prayer " salaat el jumuah" is correct to be conducted for 2 or more , because of this narrative "الاثنان فما فوقهما جماعة" which means anything above 2 is jamaat. El shookany said : "jumuah prayer is a jamaat prayer and there will be no exception unless there is a proof , and there is no proof, there is no proven narrative talking about the minimum number of people in salaat el jumaah." 
I hope this help .

Comment: so, you are saying 2 people are enough for jumah prayer, one recite qutba and other hear it!. your references are generic, please be specific to jumuah prayer, since it is different from other fard prayers.

Comment: my reference is a textbook called "فقه السنة" and what i just translated it was under the title "العدد الذى تنعقد به الجمعة" which means the number for conduction a friday prayer ,  i don't think my reference can be more specific :)

Comment: and yes , pretty much , you just need one emam and one mosaly

Comment: and as i said in my answer, there were NO narratives specific to jumah prayer when it comes to the number

Comment: Need to be mentioned: Going to a mosque has got to be the first choice. +1

Answer (score 3):

There are different opinions as to the number of people needed to perform the Friday prayer, which I shall summarize according to the Mazhabs as follows:

- **Shafi'i and Hanbali**: The number of people needed is 4, excluding the imam.
- **Maliki**: The number of people needed is 12, excluding the imam
- **Hanafi**: The number of people needed is 3, excluding the imam.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you check out our [help].  Please edit your question so to add a source, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

according to the text referenced a jamaat is 2 or more, so apply the knowledge which has been granted to you, the imam conveys to a jamaat if it's just him and 1other then he is conveying to 1 single person not 2 or more which is constituted as a jamaat. so it is logical that there must be at least 2 other than the imam, is it starting to make scents. Applying knowledge in it's simplistic form "with out external attachments/ interference" leads to the acquiring of wisdom...

Comment: if you can add your reference in your answer, that would be better.